# Sending a Word Document as an email

Tags: c#, .net, email, ms-word

In Microsoft Word 2007 it is possible to send a document as the body of an email; text, pictures, and format. Is there any way to use the 'Send Mail to Recipient' option of Word in C#? And if it is possible how would I go about doing it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a Microsoft Word addin to do this. For basic on this check microsoft site: [Word solutions with Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/hh128772)

And you can do something like below to solve your quesstion. The code will send the mail when you save the document. With a word addin you have alot of events you can cacth and do your own stuff. Or you can add your own button, if you want to send the mail by clicking a button.

```
void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.DocumentBeforeSave += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeSaveEventHandler(DocumentSave);
}

void DocumentSave(Word.Document doc, ref bool test, ref bool test2)
{
    if(doc is Word.Document)
    {                
        SendMailWithAttachment(doc);
    }
}

public void SendMailWithAttachment(Word.Document doc)
{
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    NetworkCredential basicCredential = new NetworkCredential(MailConst.Username, MailConst.Password);
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(MailConst.Username);

    // setup up the host, increase the timeout to 5 minutes
    smtpClient.Host = MailConst.SmtpServer;
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtpClient.Credentials = basicCredential;
    smtpClient.Timeout = (60 * 5 * 1000);

    message.From = fromAddress;
    message.Subject = subject;
    message.IsBodyHtml = false;
    message.Body = body;
    message.To.Add(recipient);

    var attachmentFilename = doc.FullName

    if (attachmentFilename != null)
    {
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment(attachmentFilename, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        ContentDisposition disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition;
        disposition.CreationDate = File.GetCreationTime(attachmentFilename);
        disposition.ModificationDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(attachmentFilename);
        disposition.ReadDate = File.GetLastAccessTime(attachmentFilename);
        disposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(attachmentFilename);
        disposition.Size = new FileInfo(attachmentFilename).Length;
        disposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;
        message.Attachments.Add(attachment);                
    }

    smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: Am I able to run this code in a C# project so that the entire process is automated or will this only work as an add in to Word?

Comment: You can run it as a C# word add in project and thereby debug and so forth. But the functionality you are asking for is only possible through a add in. Maybe you can do something with macros, but i don't know if you can do that in word.